# Simple keyboard in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to make simple keyboard  in angular. I need to enable keyboard when user click on textbox but I am getting permanent keyboard when I am running my application. My code is as follows::

```
app.component.html:

<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <input (input)="onInputChange($event)" class="input" value={{value}} placeholder="Tap on the virtual keyboard to start" />
    <div class="simple-keyboard"></div>
</div>

app.component.ts:

import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import Keyboard from 'simple-keyboard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../../node_modules/simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css',
    './app.component.css'
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = '';
  keyboard: Keyboard;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.keyboard = new Keyboard({
      onChange: input => this.onChange(input),
      onKeyPress: button => this.onKeyPress(button)
    });
  }

  onChange = (input: string) => {
    this.value = input;
    console.log('Input changed', input);
  };

  onKeyPress = (button: string) => {
    console.log('Button pressed', button);

    /**
     * If you want to handle the shift and caps lock buttons
     */
    if (button === '{shift}' || button === '{lock}') this.handleShift();
  };

  onInputChange = (event: any) => {
    this.keyboard.setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  handleShift = () => {
    let currentLayout = this.keyboard.options.layoutName;
    let shiftToggle = currentLayout === "default" ? "shift" : "default";

    this.keyboard.setOptions({
      layoutName: shiftToggle
    });
  };
}
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

[output_keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlzHg.png)

Application is loaded with keyboard. But I want that when I click on text box then keyboard should be enabled. How I can do  that?

Comment: I don't know about your keyboard, I supouse that your keyBoard can has a `@Input()` that you pass a NgControl -a ngControl is anything with [(ngModel)], [formControlName] or [formControl] and each (click) on key change the NgControl. In focus of the input a variable "keyBoardOn" equals to true, a (blur) equals to false and a *ngFir show or not the keyboard. But repeat I can not imagine your keyboard component or even if it's a component

Answer (score 0):

try this i think work as you expect

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <input on-focus="onInputFocus()" (input)="onInputChange($event)" class="input" value={{value}} placeholder="Tap on the virtual keyboard to start" />
    <div class="simple-keyboard"></div>
</div>

app.component.ts:

import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import Keyboard from 'simple-keyboard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    '../../node_modules/simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css',
    './app.component.css'
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = '';
  keyboard: Keyboard;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

onInputFocus() {
this.keyboard = new Keyboard({
      onChange: input => this.onChange(input),
      onKeyPress: button => this.onKeyPress(button)
    });
}

  onChange = (input: string) => {
    this.value = input;
    console.log('Input changed', input);
  };

  onKeyPress = (button: string) => {
    console.log('Button pressed', button);

    /**
     * If you want to handle the shift and caps lock buttons
     */
    if (button === '{shift}' || button === '{lock}') this.handleShift();
  };

  onInputChange = (event: any) => {
    this.keyboard.setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  handleShift = () => {
    let currentLayout = this.keyboard.options.layoutName;
    let shiftToggle = currentLayout === "default" ? "shift" : "default";

    this.keyboard.setOptions({
      layoutName: shiftToggle
    });
  };
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggxgjg

Comment: can you explain what mistake I was doing?

Comment: "on-focus="onInputFocus()"

Comment: i used your code and console throwing "KEYBOARD_DOM_ERROR" this error